# How to present view bottom to top when using navigationController

Tags: ios

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

With above code, the "ViewController" moves from right-to-left.

**Is it possible to present "ViewController" bottom-to-top?**

I tried but it does not work.

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

I created "Navigation Controller" as follows

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: If anyone happens to come across this while working with a SFSafariViewController check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008090/sfsafariviewcontroller-presentviewcontroller-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most bottom-to-top animations of a new view controller involve the presentation of the view controller using:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Your code involves a navigation stack push, which is usually a right-to-left animation.

Comment: thanks...I just realized it myself...I will accept the answer once I am allowed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a view controller then on button click event you have to write following code.
I hope this will work for you :

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([DetailViewController class]) bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```