# SFSafariViewController presentViewController animation

Tags: ios, swift

When I call `presentViewController(mySafariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`, the view always animates from the right side like a navigation controller.

I tried calling `mySafariViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical` but it doesn't work.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had to call `mySafariViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` (Swift 3 syntax)

Comment: Looks like SFSafariViewController has different default behaviour that other view controller towards modal presentation.